Unable to execute iOS Project in React Native

I have a react native project setup and configured for both android and iOS.
For both these OS I am able to build the project and execute it successfully only for android.
Not able to figure out what is missing in the configuration for iOS.
Tried this in macOS for the setup for both android and iOS.
Refer the error image attached for better clarity.
Tried the steps for setting up the project for iOS as per the official documentation of react native.
Below is the content of package.json file
{
  "name": "MyProject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "npx react-native run-android --variant=devDebug --appIdSuffix=dev",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "android:qa": "npx react-native run-android --variant=qaDebug --appIdSuffix=qa",
    "android:sit": "npx react-native run-android --variant=sitDebug --appIdSuffix=sit",
    "android:prod": "npx react-native run-android --variant=prodDebug --appIdSuffix=prod",
    "android:uat": "npx react-native run-android --variant=uatDebug --appIdSuffix=uat",
    "ios:uat": "npx react-native run-ios --scheme 'uatDebug'"
  },
  "sdkDependencies": {
    "SalesforceMobileSDK-Android": "https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android.git#v11.1.0",
    "SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS": "https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS.git#v10.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.19.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^7.6.1",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "11.1.0",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.3.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "fuse.js": "3.2.0",
    "geolib": "^3.3.4",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.14",
    "react-native-actions-sheet": "0.8.29",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1301.0",
    "react-native-config": "^1.5.1",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^7.3.1",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.12.0",
    "react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.6.3",
    "react-native-force": "git+https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-ReactNative.git#v11.1.0",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.12.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-maps": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-marquee-view": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.8.4",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.2.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "2.11.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.0",
    "react-native-screens": "3.29.0",
    "react-native-shimmer-placeholder": "^2.0.9",
    "react-native-skeleton-placeholder": "^5.2.4",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.10.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.2.1",
    "react-native-view-shot": "^3.8.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^13.6.2",
    "react-native-youtube-iframe": "^2.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.1",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "sp-react-native-in-app-updates": "^1.3.1",
    "victory-native": "^36.6.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.72.2",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.72.7",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/metro-config": "^0.76.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.76.5",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-devtools": "^4.28.0",
    "react-native-flipper": "^0.207.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0",
    "redux-flipper": "^2.0.2",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16"
  }
}


Clear Pods and reinstall them.

First of all Update your node version to latest v20 or v18,
then you can try this useful clean scripts:
For Android:
watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-* && rm -rf node_modules && rm -rf yarn.lock && yarn cache clean && yarn && cd android && ./gradlew cleanBuildCache && cd ..

For iOS:
watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-* && rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData && rm -rf node_modules && rm -rf yarn.lock && rm -rf ios/build && yarn cache clean && yarn && cd ios && pod install --repo-update && cd ..

